# Image processing with numpy arrays

Tags: image, python-imaging-library

In the grayscale mode, 255 indicates white. So if all elements of the numpy matrix are 255, should not it be a white image?

```
l = np.full((184,184),255)
j = Image.fromarray(l,'L')
j.show()
```

I am getting a black-and-white vertical striped image as output instead of pure white image. Why is it so?

Comment: confirm.. I got the same result using Canopy/ipython on Windows10.  What's odd is when I change array size to 185,185, the lines all go diagonal.  184,184 = vertical lines.

Comment: yes, my project was not working due to this and finally after lots of debugging, I found this as the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is the 'L' Mode.  L = 8 bit pixels, black and white.  The array you created is likely 32 bit values.

Try `j = Image.fromarray(l, 'I')        ## (32-bit signed integer pixels)`

[reference.](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/5.1.x/handbook/concepts.html#concept-modes)

(note: Many thanks to you for introducing me to the Pillow Image module for Python with this posting...)

Complete test code:

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
l = np.full((184,184),255)
j = Image.fromarray(m, 'I')
j.show()
```

Comment: Thanks, I used image.convert('L') to change it into required grayscale mode, ie, j.convert('L')